# How do I convert a double to a fraction in a format suitable for representing inches?

Tags: java, math

I am using the Apache Commons [math.Fraction](http://commons.apache.org/math/api-1.2/org/apache/commons/math/fraction/Fraction.html) class to convert my doubles to fractions, which is working fine.

However, I need it to calculate these fractions in a way that makes sense for displaying lengths in **inches**, to the nearest 1/32".

For example, converting 0.325 to a fraction yields 12/37, which doesn't make sense to someone looking at a US ruler. I suppose I want to round the decimal to the nearest .03125 before i convert it, if that makes sense. My basic math skills are failing me :(

**edit**
To clarify, all the input is in decimal inches between 0 and 1. Given the sample input above, I would want 5/16".

Comment: What is your number to start with? Already inches? Please give sample input and desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

can you multiply the fractional part by 32 then round?

Comment: thanks marco. this is the painfully obvious answer i was looking for